# How to remove spaces between specific word using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove spaces from a specific word in a string. For example, consider below query as input string

```
SELECT LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )
```

Now I want to remove spaces between LTRIM, RTRIM braces, and content inside it and not from the entire string.

So the final output should be

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_NAME])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_ADDR])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_TYPE])) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )
```

I have tried the following solution but it replaces all the spaces -

```
var source = "SELECT LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM
( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )";

source = Regex.Replace(source, "\\s(\\s?)\\s*", "$1");
```

So is it possible to create a regular expression to remove spaces only from specific words in a string?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: In general case you want a *parser* since `LTRIM` can appear as a part of a string, comment etc. `select 'my LTRIM ((' as "LTRIM (())" from dual -- LTRIM (` - here we have *string*, *quotation* and *comment* which should be *preserved intact*

Comment: To add to the above, honestly this is something which should be handled by your IDE, which probably has a code cleanup function.  I'm certain this exists for IntelliJ and Eclipse, not sure about Visual Studio.

Comment: If your substrings where whitespace should be removed can be matched with `@"\bLTRIM\s*\(\s*RTRIM\s*\([^()]*\)\s*\)"`, the problem can be solved with a single regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use lookbehind and lookahead:

```
var source = "SELECT LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )";
source = Regex.Replace(source, @"((?<=LTRIM)(\s)|(?<=RTRIM)\s+(?=\()|(?<=\()\s+|\s+(?=\)))", "");
Console.WriteLine(source);
```

Output:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_NAME])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_ADDR])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_TYPE])) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE (EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

Test and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/agq0V5/1

**Note**: In order to simplify it, it will also remove spaces inside `WHERE` braces, is it that bad?

**EDIT**

Here the solution chaining groups without matching spaces inside `WHERE` braces.

```
var source = "SELECT LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )";
source = Regex.Replace(source, @"(LTRIM)(\s*)(\()(\s*)(RTRIM)(\s*)(\()(\s*)([^ ]*)(\s*)(\))(\s*)(\))", "$1$3$5$7$9$11$13");
Console.WriteLine(source);
```

Output:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_NAME])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_ADDR])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_TYPE])) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )
```

**EDIT 2**

Another solution would be remove the `FROM` part, then replace the spaces near braces, then add the missing part.

```
var source = "SELECT LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )";
var from_part = Regex.Match(source,  @"FROM.*");
var partial_source = Regex.Replace(source, @"FROM.*", "");

source = Regex.Replace(partial_source, @"(\s+(?=\))|(\s+(?=\())|(?<=\()(\s+))", "");

var final_string = source + from_part.Value;
Console.WriteLine(final_string);
```

Output:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_NAME])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_ADDR])), LTRIM(RTRIM([EMPOYEE_TYPE])) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID )
```

This will also match `LTRIM()` `RTRIM()` `LTRIM(RTRIM())` `RTRIM(LTRIM())` and any other combinations.

Test and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/28nfTE/1

Comment: Thanks, @ALFA - But it is not expected to remove spaces from any other string except LTRIM RTRIM. WIll it be possible if Order of LTRIM and RTRIM changes? As its dynamic string and input string can be of any combination like LTRIM(RTRIM(column name)) Or LTRIM() Or RTRIM() or RTRIM(LTRIM(column name))

Comment: Check my answer now, I added an alternative solution for your request. You should add alternatives to it, it's way too complicated now to also match empty braces and RTRIM(LTRIM()). I will try to figure out a better way meanwhile.

Comment: Check my EDIT 2, see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of the Replace's MatchEvaluator to handle the actual dirty work.

Using a basic pattern of `\s([LR])TRIM\s` we will identify our target TRIM words with spaces. Within that pattern we will create a subgroup which will identify by an `L` or an `R` what needs to be provided and that is found at `.group[1].value`. Hence that group will tell us whether to put in the `{SP}LTRIM` or the no space `RTRIM`.

```
string txt = "SELECT LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM ( RTRIM ( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID  )";

Regex.Replace(txt, @"\s([LR])TRIM\s", new MatchEvaluator( mtch => {

return (mtch.Groups[1].Value == "L") ? $" LTRIM" : "RTRIM";

} ));
```

Returns

```
 SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM( [EMPOYEE_NAME] ) ), LTRIM(RTRIM( [EMPOYEE_ADDR] ) ), LTRIM(RTRIM( [EMPOYEE_TYPE] ) ) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ( EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID  )
```